# Why do I get error in matrix when I try to web scrape a table?

Tags: r, matrix, web-scraping, rvest

This is a sample of my code. The problem lies with the 2nd link (for Cedar Realty Trust).

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

urls <- list(c("CEDAR FAIR L P ", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/811532/000081153219000037/exhibit212018subsidiaries.htm"),
             c("CEDAR REALTY TRUST, INC.    ", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/761648/000156459020004590/cdr-ex211_8.htm"),
             c("Celanese Corp ", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1306830/000130683020000018/ex211-10k123119.htm"))

List.Of.Tabs <- map(urls, ~ {

  name <- .x[1]
  link <- .x[2]
  Sys.sleep(2)
  webpage <- read_html(link)
  tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
  tbls_ls <- html_table(tbls, fill = TRUE)
  pos1 <- possibly(function(tbls) bind_rows(tbls) %>% 
                     filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Singapore", "SGP"))) %>%
                     mutate(name = name) 
                   , otherwise = NA)

  pos1(tbls_ls)
})
```

The error message that I got:

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

How can I amend my code to take care of this error?

Comment: Please state or show the libraries you have loaded. Many of your function are from user-contributed packages.

Comment: @Edward added the libraries

Comment: Thanks. The offending line is: `html_table(tbls, fill = TRUE)`. It runs through about 6 times, but on the 7th run it crashes because the table object `tbls` is empty. I don't know enough about web scraping or the rvest package to help. But if it works for the other two web pages, and not the second, then something is different for the second web page and the html_table function is not parsing it correctly. The problem could also be with the `html_nodes` function. If no one else can help, then I'd send an email to the author of the rvest package.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to do it with `tryCatch`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

map(urls, ~ {

  name <- .x[1]
  link <- .x[2]
  Sys.sleep(2)
  tryCatch({
     temp <- link %>%
               read_html() %>%
               html_nodes("table") %>%
               html_table(fill = TRUE) 
      map_df(temp, ~filter_all(.x, any_vars(. %in% c("Singapore", "SGP")))) %>%
          mutate(name = name) 
      }, error = function(e) NA
     )
})


#[[1]]
#[1] X1   X2   name
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#                                             X1 X2        X3 X4           name
#1                            Celanese PTE. LTD. NA Singapore NA Celanese Corp 
#2  Celanese Singapore Acetyls Holding PTE. LTD. NA Singapore NA Celanese Corp 
#3 Celanese Singapore Chemical Holding PTE. LTD. NA Singapore NA Celanese Corp 
#4                  Celanese Singapore PTE. LTD. NA Singapore NA Celanese Corp 
#5              Celanese Singapore VAM PTE. LTD. NA Singapore NA Celanese Corp 
#6        Celanese Singapore Emulsions PTE. LTD. NA Singapore NA Celanese Corp
```

Although this gives the warning but it runs without an error.